# Is it possible to run meshlab or matlab on Rasbberry Pi 4 OS?

Tags: pi-4, matlab

I'm planning to use rpi 4 8gb 64bit OS.
Is it possible to run meshlab or matlab? I'm planning to convert data of a 3D scanner to a point cloud and export it as an stl file for printing. Please recommend any better converting program supporting Raspberry Pi 4 if there is one.

Comment: I am using [octave](https://wiki.octave.org/Rasperry_Pi) on an rpi400 under Ubuntu MATE with no problem. It runs .m files just fine.  Octave does much of what you would need from matlab.

Answer (score 1):

[Meshlab](https://packages.debian.org/buster/meshlab) being open-source, there should be no problem running it on a Pi. The same is true for [GNU Octave](https://packages.debian.org/buster/octave).

MATLAB currently has no support for ARM architecture. Apparently an aarch64 version is in development which will target Apple M1 CPUs, but I wouldn't expect it to work on a Pi.

Note that you can always run [MATLAB Online](https://matlab.mathworks.com/) on any computer with a Web browser.